# Why does Spotify automatically open when I boot my PC?

Tags: windows, boot, automation, spotify

For some reason, when I boot up Microsoft Windows NT 10.0 (Windows 10), Spotify automatically launches automatically, and, when it does, its taskbar icon flashes orange. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the Task Manager, and click on the Startup tab, you can control which programs start when the computer boots. Right-click Spotify and click "Disable".